# Deleted boot partition on running system

Tags: linux, ubuntu

While distracted I deleted the boot partition on my running Ubuntu Ubuntu 20.04.1 system. I'm currently backing up my data to a external hdd.

Is there anything I can do to add the partitions back without performing a reinstall?

Comment: Restore from backup?

Comment: @MichaelHampton I don't have a backup of that

Comment: Do you have another system with Ubuntu 20.04.1 and same architecture?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I did to get my system running again...

Before restarting I backed up my data.

Installed a 2nd nvme.

Installed the same version of Ubuntu to the new drive.

Booted into the new Ubuntu install.

Recreated the boot partition on the original drive.

Copied the contents of the new boot partition to the original boot partition using dd.

Copied the MBR of the new dive to the original drive using dd. (Not sure if this was necessary)

Shut down the machine and removed the 2nd nvme drive.

Powered on the machine which got me to the grub prompt.

Set grub to boot using something like the following.

```
grub> set prefix=(hd0,1)/boot/grub
grub> set root=(hd0,1)
grub> insmod normal
grub> normal
```

This booted me into the Ubuntu install.

Reinstalled grub using the following commands:

```
sudo grub-install /dev/nvme0n1p1
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Update fstab to point to the correct boot partition by running the following command and looking for the UUID vfat partition.

```
sudo blkid
```

Then update fstab file.

```
UUID=A39E-930E  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
```

Rebooted the machine and it booted up successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Restore test the backup to confirm the backup got a copy of the data.

Create and format a `/boot` partition.

Reinstall kernel packages with `apt install --reinstall`

Create another test host with identical hardware and the same set of packages. If necessary, copy `/boot` over to finish the reinstall.

Schedule a downtime to reboot, confirm system can still come back up.